# Street View Not Working in Firefox

Tags: google-maps-api-3

Live page is here:
http://teamclarke.com/teamclarke/?listing=2-251-east-8th-street

The street view works in IE9, and Chrome. Just get a grey box with FF11

```
jQuery(function() {
            // Handler for .ready() called.
            var center = new google.maps.LatLng(44.230065,-76.50000);

            var svOptions = {
                position: center,
                visible:true
            };

            var sv = new google.maps.StreetViewPanorama(document.getElementById('pano'),svOptions);
            //initialize();
        });
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's caused by style-rules for **`.entry-content img`**, they also affect the images of the StreetView.

Add this to your styles:

```
#pano img {
    border: none !important;
    max-width: none !important;
}
```